# How to assess the loss of information when mapping a set of points in an Euclidean space into a non-embedded graph?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, information-theory

Let $\{\mathbf{x}_i\}_{i=1}^N$ be a set of $N$ points such that $\mathbf{x_i} \in \mathbb{R}^M$.

Now, assume we define the graph $G=(V,E)$ such that for each point $\mathbf{x}_i$ we define a node $v_i \in V$ and we assign an undirected edge between node $v_i$ and node $v_j$ if the distance $|\mathbf{x}_i - \mathbf{x}_j| < \delta_0 $.

Clearly, a weighted graph based on the Euclidean pairwise distances will have more information on the set of data points, however, if it makes it easier I think we can assume that the graph’s adjacency matrix is binary.

Is there something similar to the [Johnson–Lindenstrauss lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Lindenstrauss_lemma) to quantify how "lossy" this transformation is or maybe to find the least lossy $\delta_0$ based on how $\mathbf{x}_i$ are distributed in $\mathbb{R}^M$.

In some sense, every non one-to-one (non-injective) map of an input domain will be lossy, e.g., $(x, y)\to x+y$ is an irreversible mapping. However, it's still informative to know the sum of two numbers than knowing nothing.

Comment: Do you keep the values of the distances or only the graph?

Comment: @Miguel to be honest I would be happy to consider both the weighted graph and the binary graph.

Comment: Reconstructing the vectors from the distances is the problem of multidimensional scaling, if I recall correctly https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling